# how can I implement a symbol type?

Tags: compiler-construction, yacc, lex

I'm doing compiler construction class but I'm having a lot of confusions. I know what .l and .y file do but it's not clear to me how they are incorporated? Where is the symbol table declared? In .l, .y or in other .c file and to make a simple compiler is .l and .y file required?

Please give me examples as it's easier for me to understand seeing examples.
Thanks.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641701/excellent-online-tutorial-for-lex-and-yacc or your instructor

Answer (score 1):

The symbol table would be declared in other .c and .h files, separate from `lex` and `yacc` files.

Lex (.l files) and Yacc (.y files) help in compiler construction, but not strictly necessary. You can write the lexer and parser by hand, for example.

Comment: so, if I want to insert a token in the symbol table, I can simply call the insert function in the .l file and insert it? And what does yylex do?